# Remove elements from a list in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe where a column has elements in a list and also single elements non-list like the one bellow:

```
             Country                                              Roles  \
0  Shell Record  [DSC Payroll Administrator Reporting, DSC HR S...   
1            PL  [DSC Payroll Administrator Reporting, DSC Payr...   
2            ES  [DSC HR Business Partner Reporting, DSC HR Bus...   
3  Shell Record  [DSC HR Business Partner Reporting, DSC HR Bus...   
4  Shell Record                     DSC BPM Worklist Administrator   

          Role vs Family  
0           Do not match  
1  [Match, Do not match]  
2                  Match  
3           Do not match  
4           Do not match
```

Is there a way that I could remove all elements that are inside a list so they are not inside the list anymore but in the same cell yet? For example, the second row in the column "Role vs Job Family" instead of the value being `"[Match, Do not match]"` it would be `"Match, Do not match"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a way to do it:

```py
df['Role vs Family'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split('[')[-1].split(']')[0])
```

It forces the value into a string, and then splits on `'['` and `']'`, each time effectively getting rid of the bracket. If it it's not there, since it wasn't a list to begin with, no harm done.

Note that this assumes none of your string values contain a square bracket inside of them...

Comment: Thanks! It worked! After forcing the values into string I could remove the left " ' " with "str.replace".